# Cannot locate bindings file on startup in node.js app

Tags: node.js, npm, binding

I have an old `node.js` app that I'm resurrecting that I wrote a couple years ago. I'm updating the packages and dependencies inside it, but I've run into a major problem that prevents the program from running.

Each time I try to initiate the application while inside the `myApplication` folder, using either `node app.js` or `nodemon`, I get the following error 22 times:

```
{ Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Debug/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/out/Debug/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/Debug/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/out/Release/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/Release/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/default/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/compiled/11.13.0/darwin/x64/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/release/install-root/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/debug/install-root/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/default/install-root/bson.node
    → /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/lib/binding/node-v67-darwin-x64/bson.node
       at bindings (/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:126:9)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/ext/index.js:10:30)
       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
       at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/index.js:1:12)
     tries:
      [ '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Debug/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/out/Debug/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/Debug/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/out/Release/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/Release/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/default/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/compiled/11.13.0/darwin/x64/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/release/install-root/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/debug/install-root/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/addon-build/default/install-root/bson.node',
        '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/lib/binding/node-v67-darwin-x64/bson.node' ] }
```

Some background information:

```
sw_vers
    ProductName:    Mac OS X
    ProductVersion: 10.14.3
    BuildVersion:   18D109
node -v
    v11.13.0
npm -v
    6.7.0
```

I have tried a number of things to get it to work, and have gone through a variety of other stack overflow threads. Initially I tried to use:

```
npm update
npm install
```

This updated all the packages to their current form, but did not eliminate the error. I made sure that `xcode-select` was installed and updated. Still, same error.

I moved on to remove the entire `node_modules` folder and rebuilt it using this code:

```
npm install node-gyp -g
npm cache clean -f
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

I get the following install runtime output telling me that there are issues with `bson-ext` and `node bin/postinstall`

```
> fsevents@1.2.7 install /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
[fsevents] Success: "/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v67-darwin-x64/fse.node" is installed via remote

> bson-ext@1.0.5 install /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


> nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

added 1044 packages from 1088 contributors and audited 15069 packages in 10.556s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I still get the same failure. As a note, I tried to use both a global and local installation for `node-gyp`.

I specifically called out the offending package, `bson-ext` and used `npm` to reinstall it

```
npm install bson-ext
```

I also went down the `node-gyp` and `python` rabbit hole

```
node-gyp rebuild
    gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
    gyp info using node@11.13.0 | darwin | x64
    gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/node-v11.13.0-headers.tar.gz
    gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/node-v11.13.0-headers.tar.gz
    gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
    gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python2
    gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
    gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-f',
    gyp info spawn args   'make',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/build/config.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-I',
    gyp info spawn args   '/Users/myUser/.node-gyp/11.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/myUser/.node-gyp/11.13.0',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/myUser/.node-gyp/11.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
    gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
    gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
    gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
    gyp info spawn args   'build',
    gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
    gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication) while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:193:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:255:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/11.13.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/myUser/folder/myApplication
    gyp ERR! node -v v11.13.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
```

I also took an older version of the missing file, `bson.node`, and pasted into the `/Users/myUser/folder/myApplication/node_modules/bson-ext/build/` directory. It gave a notice that it was built using an old node version and as a result the application won't run.

The `package.json` file includes the appropriate dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "myApplication",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-daterangepicker": "^0.2.3-alpha1",
    "angular-nvd3": "^1.0.9",
    "bindings": "^1.5.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.30",
    "bson": "^4.0.2",
    "bson-ext": "^1.0.5",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "debug": "^3.2.6",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "grunt": "^1.0.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongodb-extended-json": "^1.10.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-gyp": "^3.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.3",
    "selectize": "^0.12.6",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

How can I fix the issue that I'm having so that this program will run? Is there some way that I'm missing for `bson.node` to be created??

Comment: wouldn't it be a good idea to upgrade both bson & bson-ext instead of only bson-ext?  Maybe some other information:  in which environment did this package last work?

Comment: from what I understand, the error would come from not having a correct build environment.  maybe a re-install/verification of node-gyp will help

Comment: `bson` is included in the `npm upgrade && npm install` call as it is listed as a carat dependency in my `package.json` file. As a result, it is updated. The environment that it last worked in was using `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 59`, whereas the current standard is using `NODE_MODULE_VERSION 67`

Comment: I have tried re-installing `node-gyp` multiple times

Comment: My last guess :)  (found on the Internet) try to run  `node-gyp configure`  from the root directory of your node module.

Comment: @jcuypers I added more information after the cleaned cache, deleted folder installation

Comment: sorry, not much more to add really.  had it one time myself and it was a load of ...   good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `bson-ext`. My application was searching for version `1.0.5`, while version `2.0.1` was the newest version. This fixed the problem.

Version `1.0.5` of `bson-ext` had an internal dependency on `nan@2.4.0`, which was not functioning with `node@v11`.